# How to manually extract a backup set made by duplicity?

Tags: backup, tar, gzip, duplicity

I have a set of files on my webserver produced by duplicity software:

- duplicity-full.20110315T085334Z.vol1.difftar.gz
- duplicity-full.20110315T085334Z.vol2.difftar.gz
- duplicity-full.20110315T085334Z.vol3.difftar.gz
- etc... (50 files, total size about 1 Gb)

Backup has been made without encryption.

My current hoster haven't duplicity on his server and don't want to install it. How can I unpack these files using remote SSH access? Maybe there is some bash-script available to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about download the required archive and then make like this:
duplicity scp://uid@other.host//usr/backup restored_dir (example from official site)

Comment: It is possible but slow: 1 GB to download and then 4-5 GB to upload. Sure if there will be no other way to do this directly on server, I'll use this method. :(

Comment: ok. Seems there is no other way except this

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone else comes across this (as I just have) there are some reasonably detailed (and *mostly* correct) steps [over here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase#Restoring_by_Hand).

**Key details**

The key point is to unpack all of the `duplicity-full.*.difftar.gz` files in the same place, so that you're left with just two `snapshot/` and `multivol_snapshot/` directories.

If your file is in `snapshot/` then you're done.  Otherwise find the directory in `multivol_snapshot/` at the path where your file used to be: you need to join together all the files in this directory to recreate the original file.  The files are numbered, and can be joined together using the `cat` command.  Depending on how large the original was, there may be many parts.

**Problem with original instructions**

The directions linked above suggest using `cat * > rescued-file`.  Unfortunately this simple approach fails if you have more than 9 parts.  Since `*` expands in dictionary order, not numeric order, `10` would be listed before `2`, and the file would be reconstructed in the wrong order.

**Workaround**

One simple approach is to remember that dictionary order *does* work when numbers are the same length, and that `?` matches a single character.  So if your largest file has *three* digits, you can manually enter:

```
cat ? ?? ??? > rescued-file
```

Add or remove `?` patterns as necessary, depending on the largest file number.

**Script**

If you have a lot of files to recover and don't fancy typing that for all of them, you might prefer to use a script such as this.  It lists the containing directory for every file, removes duplicates from the list, then goes to each directory and creates a `content` file from the fragments there.  (`spacer` is just to make `$1` work.)

```
find multivol_snapshot/ -type f -printf '%h\0' | \
  sort -uz | \
  xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'cd "$1" ; cat $(ls | sort -n) > content' spacer
```

Now you just have to add `/content` to the end of any filename you were looking for, and you should find it.

**Limitations**

This doesn't restore any of the original file permissions or ownership.  It also doesn't deal with incremental backups, but then the [linked instructions](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase#Restoring_by_Hand) also hit a bit of a dead end on this point — they just suggest using `rdiff` 'to stitch the files together' and refer the reader to `man rdiff`.

Comment: [this](http://sashikasuren.blogspot.in/2013/01/duplicity-backup-restore-process.html) links has a java program for the recovery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unzip those archives, and copy needed files. I do not know how it backup files, but i think it copy files to the dir and gzip it (or tar.gz)

Comment: Each .difftar.gz volume has 2 subfolders inside: "snapshot" and "multivol_snashot". Each file in "multivol_snapshot" folder represented as folders containing parts of that file (1, 2, 3 etc). I have no idea how to unpack them correctly

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think, it's better to use backup software (or script) that can be simply extracted. You can see for backuppc, flaxbackup (I don't know will it work on your host or not, if it's vps (or vds) it will, but if it's just shared hosting it will not).

Comment: it's a virtual hosting, neither backuppc nor flexbackup available.